# Passing a Dictionary to WCF service

Tags: c#, dictionary, wcf

I need to pass a Dictionary (with max 20,000 entries) to a WCF service. Can I pass it all by once?

```
void SubmitDictionary(Dictionary<string, MyEntry> val);
```

where MyEntry is :

```
class MyEntry
{
    string Name;
    long Age;
}
```

Is there a configuration for size of the value passed? Or can we pass as large data as this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things I need to know.

1. What type of binding r u using ?  Like `BasicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding`.  If you are using `wsHttpBinding` you don't need to worry about it's length
2. Have you made your class serializeable? If not then make it like this:

```
    [DataContract]
    public Class MyEntry
    {
          [DataMember]
          public string Name {get; set;}

          [DataMember]
          public long Age {get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: I'm using wsHttpBinding and I have decorated it with DC

Comment: then set set the 
maxBufferPoolSize="As u want" maxReceivedMessageSize="As u want" and other stuffs like maxStringContentLength="As u want" maxArrayLength="As u want"
 maxBytesPerRead="As u want" maxNameTableCharCount="As u want"

Answer (score 4):

You unfortunately have a bigger problem and that's that you can't serialize an IDictionary.

You're probably going to have to create an array or similar of a serializable custom key-value type.

Comment: XmlSerializer doesn't support this, but DataContractSerializer does.

Answer (score 3):

There's **MaxReceivedMessageSize**, **MaxStringContentLength** and **MaxBufferSize**.

Check the link

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128000850/http://geekswithblogs.net/niemguy/archive/2007/12/11/wcf-maxstringcontentlength-maxbuffersize-and-maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx)

Read related question on how to increase size

[wcf max message size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369132/wcf-max-message-size)

[Silverlight & WCF: Max message size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330034/silverlight-wcf-max-message-size)

**EDIT** Check also Service Reference's configuration. You should set **Dictionary collection type** to `Dictionary`.

Good Luck!